# git view/copy files from all commits across the history

Tags: linux, git

Let's say I:

- commited `file1.txt` in the 1st commit
- commited `file2.txt` in the 2nd commit and deleted `file1.txt`
- commited `file3.txt` in the 3rd commit and deleted `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

Now I want to see all files in the repo, across the history. Let's consider there is only the master branch.

One approach is to checkout each commit.

But I'm thinking in something more straightforward, do such a thing exist?

Let's say, i.e., I would like to zip everything (i.e. put every commit in a folder) and send to someone who doesn't know git.

Or just navigate each commit to see what's there at that point.

So, to make a question from all that: Is it possible to navigate across commits in `Windows Explorer` fashion (point and click)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for is possible. Suppose you re-introduce `file1.txt` with totally different content again after doing some unrelated commits in between. Which of the different files who are both named `file1.txt` should be included in that hypothetical ZIP file?

Comment: Both, each in a dedicated folder (named accordingly to the commit date, i.e.). Makes sense?

Comment: @DoNhuVy, question edited. Is the issue exposed now?

Comment: I think what you're asking for is a folder for each commit, which contains the whole working directory at that point, am I right? I don't think anything currently exists, you could probably write a script for it quite easily: might be simpler to show the person you're sending it to `gitk` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would using `git bundle` help?

The documentation on this can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

Note, that, this is an all or nothing solution.

This will contain, (in special format) the entire history of commits, effectively a repo of everything in that format. This can then be zipped up.

Bonus is this, when the receiver obtains the zip, all they can do is use `git clone` against the bundle to recreate the repo.